# SQL DECIMAL column that supports and converts empty OR spaces into NULL

Tags: sql-server

I have a DECIMAL field in my SQL table, and I want to support EMPTY and SPACES as well. So, when the user enters nothing OR spaces only in that field, I still want the table to take it and convert that into NULL.

I tried using CASE in an INSERT statement, in SQL. I am using it under PHP.
I tried this:

```
INSERT INTO test (id,value) VALUES ('@id',CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM('@amount')) IS NULL THEN LTRIM(RTRIM('@amount')) ELSE NULL END);
```

This doesn't work. However, the exact same statement but for UPDATE works fine!

If I can solve the problem using a different approach, please advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

[NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM('@amount')),'')](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx)

Comment: Not working. CASE is not working in the INSERT statement at all!

Comment: @johnshaddad - try to use NULLIF function